# Where does Elementor storing his code of my theme edits?

Tags: php, wordpress, elementor

I'm a beginner in learning WordPress.

I have started building a WordPress theme from scratch, using YouTube tutorial.

First I created some basic files like front-page.php and wrote some basic code in them.

Then I did some Elementor editing to My front page, but why the changes don't appear in the front-page.php file?
Where does Elementor storing his code of the edits to my front page?

Comment: `I have started building a WordPress theme from scratch` using a plugin to create a theme is not coding from scratch. from scratch you write your own codes with out any plugin help. good luck

Comment: WordPress uses a combination of PHP templates and and MySQL Database to generate content. When you are saving content from the WordPress editor, it's stored in the database and retrieved when the appropriate query is sent, it doesn't actually modify the PHP file. As long as you have the appropriate sidebars and/or `the_content()` type functions on the page template, it will pull in the content from WP.